# CloudWatch metric alarm using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

When trying to setup some CloudWatch alarms using Terraform for some reason it doesn't find the metrics and the alarm remains stuck in insufficient data. Terraform doesn't output any errors and I can find the metrics if I search manually in AWS. What am I missing here?

Example a simple healthy host alarm point to a target group:

```
#healthy host alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "health" {
  alarm_name          = "${var.tag_app}_healthy_host"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Maximum"
  threshold           = "1"
  alarm_description   = "Healthy host count for EC2 machine"
  alarm_actions       = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.blabla.arn}"]
  ok_actions          = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.blabla.arn}"]

  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = "${aws_lb_target_group.alb_target.arn_suffix}"
  }
}
```

When I select another resource (EC2, RDS) and another metric I get a CloudWatch alarm pointing to the right metric and it doesn't remain stuck at insufficient data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`HealthyHostCount` metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#w389aac17b7c13b9) is only available under either the `TargetGroup, LoadBalancer` dimensions or the `TargetGroup, AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer` so you need to at least add the `LoadBalancer` dimension as well to access this metric.

So your Terraform code should instead be:

```
#healthy host alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "health" {
  alarm_name          = "${var.tag_app}_healthy_host"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Maximum"
  threshold           = "1"
  alarm_description   = "Healthy host count for EC2 machine"
  alarm_actions       = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.blabla.arn}"]
  ok_actions          = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.blabla.arn}"]

  dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = "${aws_lb.example.arn_suffix}"
    TargetGroup  = "${aws_lb_target_group.alb_target.arn_suffix}"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know which metrics need which dimensions?

Comment: That should be asked as a separate question really.