# Terraform: Using SEARCH expressions with CloudWatch Alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I've looked over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593432/cloudwatch-metric-alarm-using-terraform) question which didn't help so much, so here it goes...

I have a bunch of Lambda functions that I want to monitor and set off a CloudWatch alarm if something goes wrong. The Lambda functions are actually prefixed with environment names, i.e. `env-1-function-1`, `env-1-function-2`, `env-2-function-1` etc.

These environments are separate, i.e. a cloudwatch alarm setup for env1 shouldn't have anything to do with env2. So to achieve this, I started to look at [SEARCH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-syntax.html) expressions.

This is my alarm:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "lambda_average_duration" {
  alarm_name          = "${local.env_prefix}-alarm-lambda_average_duration"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  threshold           = "40000"
  alarm_description   = "This alarm monitors lambda average duration and triggers if the average of durations rise above 40 seconds."
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.alarms_topic.arn]

  metric_query {
    id = "e1"
    expression = "SEARCH('{AWS/Lambda,FunctionName} MetricName=\"Duration\" FunctionName=${local.env_prefix}', 'Maximum', 60000)"
    label = "Function Name filter"
    return_data = true
  }
}
```

Where `env_prefix` will be `env-1`. This works totally fine in the AWS Console when graphing metrics.

[image: CW Console]

Now when I run Terraform, it seems to have an issue with this saying that "Updating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: Period must not be null", however [according to the Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#metric_query) on this, when supplying `metric_query` you may not specify period...

Is there a concrete way for me to limit my Lambda metrics to be filtered per environment (name filter), instead of using the Lambda functions across the whole account?

Comment: Does it apply successfully if you use a simple (but valid) mathematical expression?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the full error output? And have you tried importing the alarm you created in the console and seeing what Terraform wants to change it to in the plan?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because AWS Cloudwatch does not support alarms on SEARCH metrics.

- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11011
- [Creating a CloudWatch alarm based on a search expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543319/creating-a-cloudwatch-alarm-based-on-a-search-expression)